# Read the label of a Radio Button and confirm the value with Selenium

Tags: selenium, text, radio-button

So as the title suggests. I am looking to confirm that the value of the Radio button is correct.

The HTML is as follows:

```
<input type="radio" value="Coach" name="servClass" checked="">
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
Economy class
<br>
<input type="radio" value="Business" name="servClass">
Business class
<br>
<input type="radio" value="First" name="servClass">
First class
</font>
```

The selenium bit is as follows:

```
    String expectedServiceClass = "First class";

    String actualServiceClass = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='First']")).getText();


    if (actualserviceClass.equals(expectedServiceClass)){
        System.out.println("Correct Wording");

    }else{
        System.out.println("Oops: somethings not right with the    wording");
        //close Firefox
        driver.close();

    // exit the program explicitly
        System.exit(0); 
    }
```

But when this is executed, the actualServiceClass variable doesn't contain any values i.e. null therefore the "if statement" will always print "Oops: somethings not right with the wording"

Any help???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the current HTML code, you won't be able to confirm the value of label of Radio button as Radio button is implemented as Input tag, that is a self-closing tag and hence `getText()` on `input` will always return `null`. You will need a container tag like div to include the Input tag(radio button) and the label. Refer: [Self-closed versus Container Tags](http://www.textpattern.net/wiki/index.php?title=self-closed_versus_container_tags)

The problem is not with the Selenium Code, its actually due to the improper HTML snippet. Changing the HTML as below can solve this:

```
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
  <div>
    <input type="radio" value="Coach" name="servClass" checked="">
    Economy class
    <br>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" value="Business" name="servClass">
    Business class
    <br>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" value="First" name="servClass">
    First class
  </div>
```

After this, just changing the Css Selector or XPath to find the `div` will give you value of label of Radio Button. Css Selector can be `div>input[value='First']`. Let me know if you are able to solve the problem.

Comment: Ah great, thought i was going mad with the code :) - okay will pass on your comments to some other people so they can make it better....

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Manu the HTML snippet is poor but you can use javascript **childNodes** to get the text from the nodes

The **childNodes** property returns a collection of a node's child nodes, as a NodeList object.

The nodes in the collection are sorted as they appear in the source code and can be accessed by index numbers. The index starts at 0.

Use `executescript` to execute JavaScript in the context of the currently selected frame or window

**Below is an example in java**

Don't forget to add return since you need to return the value to the caller

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Coach']/following-sibling::font"));

String node_text=(String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue",element);

System.out.println(node_text.trim());
```

Try the above script it will return "Economy class"

In the above script we use childnode property to get all the childnodes of
font tag `<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">`

similarly you can get the other text nodes by replacing childnode index

childNodes[4]----->"Business class"

childNodes[8]------>"First class"

I tried the above code it was working fine

Hope this helps you...kindly get back if you have any queries